# How to serialize a NSDictionary/NSArray/Property List (plist) which contains NSNull

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, serialization

I want to store in a `NSMutableDictionary` some null values using `NSNull` and then serialize this data using a property list. Problem is `NSNull` is not allowed and I get "Property list is in invalid format" error. Is there a workaround for this? Seems very surprising they didn't put `NSNull` on the list of valid plist objects.

Comment: The answer provided by Saurabh Wadhwa works just great, I just used it myself, too bad the original poster is not around to accept it...

Answer (score 14):

I convert NSArray or NSDictionary to NSData before serializing. Following is a category on nsarray for serializing and deserializing. This comfortableby handles some data being nsnull

```
@implementation NSArray(Plist)

-(BOOL)writeToPlistFile:(NSString*)filename{
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    BOOL didWriteSuccessfull = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    return didWriteSuccessfull;
}

+(NSArray*)readFromPlistFile:(NSString*)filename{
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: Very good! Its amazing this works (which I just verified) when the more common methods in the keyed archivers do not.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using a property list, consider using an NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver. Properties lists have a fixed set of types, and that doesn't include NSNull, and it isn't meant to be extended.

Here are links to the relevant documentation: [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html) and [NSKeyedUnarchiver](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to put `NSNull` in a property list. (Trivia: the binary property list format actually supports nulls, but the writer doesn’t implement support.)

For a dictionary, the easiest workaround is to simply filter out the null values, so { foo = "bar"; baz = null; } becomes { foo = "bar"; }.

Comment: Its not exactly the same thing as I need the null values to indicate that the key exists but has no corresponding values (i.e. I already know there is a key with no data as opposed to its a new key which I dont know about).

Comment: Perhaps you could serialise both A) a dictionary with just the keys which have a corresponding value, and B) an array of all the known keys, regardless of if they have data attached. Ultimately there is no way to put NSNull in a plist directly so you need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of NSPropertyListSerializationClass:

> A property list object. plist must be
>   a kind of NSData, NSString, NSNumber,
>   NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary
>   object. Container objects must also
>   contain only these kinds of objects.

So you need to have one of those. Depending on the type of data, you could put in a placeholder instead of NSNull and then do a process before/after loading the .plist (like, for example, using a zero-length NSData object to represent your NSNull in the plist). Exactly what kind of placeholder would be dependent on what kind of data you are storing, and choosing something to  avoid. Then, after loading, translate the empty NSData back to NSNull.

Comment: Seriously what is wrong with the apple programmers??? I hate having to write code like that.

Comment: DD, if what you want is general serialization, use NSCoder. Property lists have a fixed set of types, so no matter how far it’s expanded there will always be a need to convert something.

Comment: If you don't like the restrictions of the property lists (which can't support NSNull, as the documentation indicates) then don't use property lists. As the other commenter suggests, use your own serialisation format. NSPropertyList support != serialization.